# Tearing in Fragment Program (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

I've been working on stylizing my lighting shader a bit, and have run into a snag.  My main development computer has an ATI card, and it renders my new lighting scene without any problems.  However, NVIDIA cards tend to show distortion, or tearing.  It almost looks like a zbuffer issue, but it completely eludes me as to what the problem could be.  I've taken a screen shot here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQIsg.png (notice the 'dithering' on the faces)

Here's the relevant section of the fragment program:

```
in vec3 vertex_color;
in vec4 vertex_position;

out vec4 fragment_color;

uniform vec3 playerPosition;

void main(void)
{
  float playerDistanceTorch = length(playerPosition - floor(vertex_position.xyz));
  float playerTorch = (160 - playerDistanceTorch * playerDistanceTorch);
  fragment_color = vec4(vertex_color, 1) * clamp(playerTorch * 0.005, 0, 1);
}
```

Again, this only seems to affect NVIDIA cards in my tests so far, so I'm pretty confused.  My first guess was floating point precision error, so I tried to keep playerTorch large for as long as possible (the original code was 0.8 - 0.005*playerDistanceTorch*playerDistanceTorch).

Edit:  Through some experimentation, I found the issue is coming from the linear interpolation of vertex_position.  If I make this value 'flat' (so that no interpolation happens), then the tearing goes away.  However, this does not give the desired effect.

Comment: Can you detail your pixel format used on both hardware? Are you using an FBO? If not, could you query the pixel format (depth buffer in particular).

Comment: I'm using GLUT to request a RGBA (32bit) with multisampling and depth.  I've tricked the system into using a larger depth buffer by also requesting a stencil buffer (a trick for Apple based computers).  Here's the code in question:  Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | Glut.GLUT_DEPTH | Glut.GLUT_ALPHA | Glut.GLUT_STENCIL | Glut.GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);  I am not using any FBOs.  The depth buffer is 24 bits on NVIDIA, ATI and Intel cards (every system I tested).

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like z-fighting, make sure your cubes are not rendered twice. Also I see that your alpha channel is modulated, maybe the blending is enabled and you have undesired blending. If that's the case, try:

```
fragment_color = vec4(vertex_color * clamp(playerTorch * 0.005, 0, 1), 1);
```

instead. Or disable blending if you don't want any.
Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Jean-Simon, I totally agree that it looks like z-fighting, but even if I only render the single VAO once (and nothing else) I can still see that same issue.  I also tried your suggestion to set the alpha to 1, but blending is already disabled during the rendering of this VAO, and I didn't notice any different.  The issue is still present on my NVIDIA tests.  I think this is a difference between how NVIDIA and ATI/Intel perform their interpolation.  If I use 'flat' for the vertex_position then I don't see this issue anymore.

Comment: Ok thank you for the precision. I don't have any idea for the moment. Anything special with the vertex shader? Any geometry shader? It looks like the interpolated vertex_position in your fragment shader is one for another fragment. You could also compute your fragment color in your vertex shader.

Comment: The vertex shader is pretty simple, and just sets vertex_position by multiplying the input vertex by the model matrix.  I wanted to do the lighting calculation in the shader, but I cannot tell which quad I am drawing just from the vertex data.  I 'tricked' the system into knowing which quad was being rendered by taking the floor of the vertex position in the fragment shader.  Since all of my squares are unit length (1x1) the floor would keep a consistent color for the entire quad.  I'm not sure how to replicate this in the vertex shader without storing further information.

Comment: Yeah computing in the vertex shader would be Gouraud shading, I think what you want is Phong shading. I'm guessing you have latest NVidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest drivers.  This same phenomena is exhibited by another NVIDIA based computer as well (a friend who tested the game).  Seems to be a consistent issue on their hardware.